# OData call with $apply=groupby((parameter)) in the url presents and error about a missing AggregationWrapper

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

When calling an OData api endpoint I get the following error: "The given model does not contain the type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.Wrapper.AggregationWrapper'."

The url that I am calling is in this format `https://localhost:7181/odata/RainMitigation?$apply=groupby((MyColumnName))`
Without the  $apply parameter the call works properly and with other parameters alone the call works properly. i.e. `$orderby=MyColumnName%20asc`

Any ideas of what might be causing this? Or any ideas on how to troubleshoot this further?

I am using:

- Micosoft.AspNetCore.OData v8.0.11
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.8"
- Microsoft.OData.Client" Version="7.12.2"
- Microsoft.OData.Core" Version="7.12.2"
- Microsoft.OData.Edm" Version="7.12.2"
- .Net 6

Comment: Please post the schema for RainMitigation from your $metadata or include the results from [https://localhost:7181/odata/RainMitigation?$select=*&$top=1&orderby=MyColumnName%20asc](https://localhost:7181/odata/RainMitigation?$select=*&$top=1&orderby=MyColumnName%20asc)

Comment: According to this [post](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/issues/420), this problem does not seem to have been solved, a long time has passed, and this problem is still being followed up

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in ASP OData 8.0.5 version. Revert your version to **8.0.4** and it shall function.

Answer (score 0):

all

i resolved problem with $apply and groupby using the next blog

[here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/aggregation-extensions-in-odata-asp-net-core/)

there are varios examples of $apply

Good luck